# Best way to communicate with stockfish (external executable) in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a chess program using stockfish as an external executable. I'm using C++ in visual studio 2019 with Windows 10. I need to be able to write commands to stockfish, and read its outputs, all whilst my main program runs normally.

Initially, I tried modifying the source code of stockfish and running it on a separate thread. It partly worked, but became very messy with mutexes and shared data.

Now I'm trying to run it as a separate executable. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301415/interfacing-with-stockfish-shell-using-c) but this solution uses fork and exec, which seem to only exist on Linux.

I also found [this](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/17685/how-to-send-uci-messages-from-c-app-to-stockfish-on-android) but that is only a solution for C#.

Finally, I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) which looks promising. But it also needs the code in the child program, which would be a problem in and of itself. Also, the code is quite long, so I was wondering if that is really the best way to go about this, or is there was a library that would make this easier?

Comment: UCI is a protocol that you have to follow. No client (engine) modification is required.

Comment: Yes I realise that now, that's why I'm now trying to use it as a separate executable, but I'm not sure what the easiest way is for me to go about this in my current situation.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found a library called boost, specifically boost.process which looks like it has what I need. It can be found [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/process.html).